# ul li tag position

Tags: html, css

I have two sets of lists with headings which need to display side-by-side as in the following image:

[image]

Here's my html:

```
<h2>Pages</h2>
<ul class="one">
     <li><a href="">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Archives</a></li>
     <li><a href="">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Archives</a></li>
</ul>

<h2>Pages</h2>
<ul class="two">
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Archives</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Archives</a></li>
</ul>
```

I can't make any changes to the html. I have to accomplish this using css only.

Please refer to the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Pxtvh/

Comment: The most elegant way to do this would be to use float property in CSS but both the <h2> and <ul> would have to be enclosed in a single parent element for this to work.

Comment: Can you use JavaScript/jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

If you could use html, I would surround each header and it's list with a

```
<div style="float:left">
```

This works, I've tried it but if you want to use entirely css, I suppose you could use the css code:

```
ul.two {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:100px;
}
```

This DOESN'T position the headers because they're both  and they don't have individual classes so other than changing the html as above, I can't think of a solution. Also, you would have to update the "left" parameter if you want to change the width of the first list.

Answer (score 0):

Like Waffle Face suggested, you can try explore using position: absolute and set left and top pixel, both for the second set of h2 and ul.

Answer (score 0):

As has been noted, you cannot do this with CSS only.

Ideally, you would be able to wrap a DIV around the group of heading and list, but you've stated that you cannot edit the html.

That leaves one alternative:  **If you can use JavaScript**, you can wrap DIVs around your header-list groupings dynamically to achieve the same effect.

Here is how you would do this with jQuery:

```
$('h2 + ul').each(function () {
    $(this).prev().andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="grouped-list"/>');
});
```

Then in your css file you would float `div.grouped-list` left.  [See a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Pxtvh/18/).

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not great because it uses position absolute, but here is my solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/Pxtvh/25/

```
h2:nth-of-type(2){
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 0;
}
ul:nth-of-type(2){
   position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ul {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

This will make the `<ul>`to float left then edit add HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>link 1</li>
    <li>link 2</li>
    <li>link 3</li>
    <li>link 4</li>
</ul>
```

Then second one:

```
<ul>
    <li>link 1 column2</li>
    <li>link 2 column2</li>
    <li>link 3 column2</li>
    <li>link 4 column2</li>
</ul>
```